# Image slide show on Livecode

Tags: livecode

I create 2 images for slide show but I have a problem. My problem is when the first image fade to the second image. The stack freeze. When image fade finish, the stack back to normal.

Code.

```
command aniFadehide curF
    Switch noFa
      case 1
         lock screen for visual effect in rect (the rect of img 1 of grp curF)
         show img 2 of grp curF
         hide img 1 of grp curF
         unlock screen with visual effect dissolve very fast
         add 1 to noFa
         break
      case 2
         lock screen for visual effect in rect (the rect of img 1 of grp curF)
         show img 1 of grp curF 
         hide img 2 of grp curF 
         unlock screen with visual effect dissolve very fast
         put 1 to noFa
         break
   end Switch
   send "aniFadehide curF" to me in 3 secs 
end aniFadehide
```

Comment: Is noFa a global variable?

Comment: Yes, I set noFa a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I do before using visual effects. First, I always load QT by getting the QTVersion. This may no longer apply to LiveCode 7, unless you set the dontUseQT to false.

Second, I execute a visual effect invisible to make sure that I have the "freeze" behind me before I really need visual effects. E.g.

```
on openStack
  lock screen for visual effect
  // nothing here, but you can but something if you want
  unlock screen with visual effect dissolve very fast
  pass openStack
end openStack
```

This handler execute a visual effect, but because you don't go to a different card and don't show or hide controls, the use is just thinking that s/he waiting for the software to start up.

Next, you seem to have a little error in your script, as `put 1 to noFa`should be `put 1 into noFa`.

There may also be an issue with your global or local variables. So, I made a working script and will post it here. This script would run in a button.

```
global noFa

local lCounter


on mouseUp
     put the pendingMessages into myMsgs
     filter myMsgs with "*aniFadehide*"
     repeat for each line myLine in myMsgs
          cancel item 1 of myLine
     end repeat
     put 1 into noFa
     put 0 into Counter
     aniFadehide 1
end mouseUp

command aniFadehide curF
     add 1 to lCounter
     Switch noFa
          case 1
               lock screen for visual effect in rect (the rect of img 1 of grp curF)
               show img 2 of grp curF
               hide img 1 of grp curF
               unlock screen with visual effect dissolve very fast
               add 1 to noFa
               break
          case 2
               lock screen for visual effect in rect (the rect of img 1 of grp curF)
               show img 1 of grp curF 
               hide img 2 of grp curF 
               unlock screen with visual effect dissolve very fast
               put 1 into noFa
               break
     end Switch
     if lCounter < 10 then
          send "aniFadehide curF" to me in 3 secs 
     end if
end aniFadehide
```